# How to migrate from Spring Security 5.x to spring 6.1.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to migrate this code to spring security 6.1.x

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I tried to use authorizeHttpRequests but it gives me 403 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On stackoverflow are a lot of posts about how to migrate but also you should read next references:

1. [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html)
2. [spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)
3. [Deprecated List](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html)

Also the `filterChain` that you provided will have next one body:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
    request.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
  });
  http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());

  http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

  http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

  return http.build();
}
```

Comment: i made an update. `http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());`

Comment: Thanks for the response and updates i think it is good that way.

Comment: if it solved the problem don`t forget to read/check the linked resources about this migration, also approve the answer/upvote

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

In the first issue, the problem lies in the requestMatcher pattern. You should change it to `"/**"` because Spring MVC's pattern matching is relative to the servlet path. This means that if you have mapped any servlet to a path that starts with "/" and is greater than one, you should use this pattern.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77179831/3856160) correctly suggests, you can use `authorizeHttpRequests` with a lambda function.